# How can we rename a file with semi-colon as part of the filename?

Tags: shell, rename, wildcards, quoting, cygwin

I tried to rename all file with extension "XLS;1" to "XLS" but it just didn't work.

I tried the following in cygwin in windows xp and they don't work:

```
mv *.XLS;1 *.XLS

mv *.XLS\;1 *.XLS

mv "*.XLS;1" *.XLS
```

Comment: I figured it out, but in the future you should include the exact error message you get, it helps a great deal in fixing things, especially like this where the actual problem isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Oh...I thought the wildcard expansion will do the trick. Now the error message make sense, which I thought was just non-sense error message.

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 (and/or @Kevin), would you please update this with "the error message(s)"?  For posterity.  :)

Comment: @PythonLarry I don't have cygwin to get the exact messages, but they should be something along the lines of "mv: foo.XLS: not a directory" and "bash: 1: command not found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the semicolon, your second example would take care of that. The problem is that Linux/Unix utilities (and, by extension, Cygwin) don't take that instruction to mean "move all files ending in `.XLS;1` to `.XLS`," as I understand Windows does. You need to move each file individually:

```
for file in *.XLS\;1; do 
    mv "$file" "${file%;1}"
done
```

An explanation:

This takes all files ending in `.XLS;1` and stores them one at a time into a variable named `$file`. For each file, we tell it to move that `$file` to a new name we create by chopping `;1` off the back of `$file`.

N.b. For those using zsh, there is a nice utility called `zmv`:

```
zmv '(*).XLS;1" "$1.XLS"
```

Depending on your setup you may need to run `autoload zmv` first (put it in your .zshrc too).

Answer (score 1):

You can move by inode.

To find the inode

```
ls -i
```

using the inode you just found

```
find . -inum <you just found> -exec mv {} <new name> \;
```

That should work on a unix system.  No idea about cygwin.

Comment: but I need rename many files.

Comment: True but not helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin has [util-linux](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=util-linux%2Futil-linux-2.21-1) package which contains `rename`:

```sh
rename ".XLS;1" ".XLS" *.XLS\;1
```

Or if there are no other semicolons in the file names, this is enough:

```sh
rename ";1" "" *.XLS\;1
```