# How do I rename files that have '|' in them?

Tags: shell, files, quoting

I am using Fedora 24.

I have tried many different ways to do this.  I've tried it under a Windows VM with the folder in question as a shared folder.

I've tried using the 'rename' command.

I've tried using the 'mv' command.

I've tried renaming them in 'Files'.

I've tried setting the filename to a variable with inode and then renaming. (lost the source)

```
26477098 'File | With Pipe.png'
xyz=`ls -i|grep 26477098|sed 's/26477098 //'`
mv "$xyz" File\ --\ With\ Pipe.png
mv: cannot stat 'File | With Pipe.png': No such file or directory
```

I keep getting the 'No such file or directory' error whatever way I try and do this.

I've also tried renaming them by using their inode number (["mv" file with garbled name by inode number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235396/mv-file-with-garbled-name-by-inode-number))

```
26477098 'File | With Pipe.png'
[user@computer Pictures]$ find . -inum 26477098 -exec mv {} File\ --\ With\ Pipe.png \;
mv: cannot move './File | With Pipe.png' to 'File -- With Pipe.png': No such file or directory
[user@computer Pictures]$ find . -inum 26477098 -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t a.png
mv: failed to access 'a.png': No such file or directory
```

If I try to open the file, it says "No images found..."

I was thinking maybe I could hard link to the inode and then try and delete the original file, but I can't figure out a way to do that.

Any thoughts?

*****************************EDIT*************************************

```
[risshuu@centurion Pictures]$ mv "File | With Pipe.png" "File -- With Pipe.png" 
mv: cannot stat 'File | With Pipe.png': No such file or directory
[risshuu@centurion Pictures]$ mv File\ \|\ With\ Pipe.png File\ --\ With\ Pipe.png
mv: cannot stat 'File | With Pipe.png': No such file or directory
```

I have quite a few of these files, and none of these work on them.

I just created a new file with a pipe and I have no problem renaming it to not have the pipe in it.  There must be something else going on as well because I can't 'cat' the contents or open the file--I can't even remove any of the files!  Are there any other file verification commands or something I can use or ways I can delete these files from the filesystem??

Comment: Are you sure there are no other special characters?  `ls -b` will show them.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  ls -b actually doesn't even escape the pipe: it shows File\ |\ With\ Pipe.png.

Comment: `mv -i ./*File*With*Pipe*png* 'Fixed Filename.png'`   - make note of the quotes (none in the first filename) so that glob matching will handle the rest of the mess.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me!  I think that there is something else going on rather than the problem just being a pipe in the filename like I thought earlier.  I tried using the command with the asterisks and I keep getting a "cannot stat" error.  (I added more info to my post)

Comment: That's now beginning to sound like a corrupted filesystem!  Or a non-native filesystem (NTFS? samba? FUSE?) which isn't playing clean...

Comment: Wow... how simple.  It was because I was accessing it as a samba share.  I SSH'd to the machine and it worked with no problems.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Risshuu is this a mounted filesystem? if it is not a remote filesystem and not your root filesystem you can try running an `fsck /dev/sd**` on the filesystem

Comment: Yes, it was a mounted samba share.  I was able to SSH into the machine and rename the files with no problems.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to just escape the pipe use a backslash

```
mv te\|st test
```

Or in your case with the space

```
mv first\ \|\ last first_last
```

If that does not work you can escape all the special characters by warping them with double quotes.

```
mv "first | last" first_last
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I tried at the start.  I did verify with a new file just to make sure and the new file worked while the old files I have do not.  I think there might be something problem with the files themselves because I keep getting `cannot stat` errors.