# Fedora: cp: Invalid argument while coping a file named with Chinese characters to a vfat filesystem

Tags: fedora, mount, cp, fat, vfat

I want to use `cp` to copy a file named with Chinese characters to my fat32 usb stick. This is done using a script, so using `nautilus` is not a solution for me. I do not want to rename the files, too. I receive an error `cp: cannot create regular file '测试.pdf': Invalid argument`. On Ubuntu, the `cp` command works perfectly.

The locale:
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8`

The USB stick is formatted using:
`sudo mkfs.vfat -n $volume_name /dev/$dev_name`

Then I create mount directory:
`sudo mkdir /run/media/piotr/$volume_name`

And then the USB stick is mounted:
`sudo mount /dev/$dev_name /run/media/piotr/$volume_name`

Comment: Please add the locale info of the shell and mount options of your FAT32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give you a few meta-answers.

First up, (just for background) [FAT32 handles UTF-8/UTF-16 filenames in an odd way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503697/unicode-filenames-on-fat-32).

More than likely, it's just a mount option (covered below)... just in case it's not though I'm covering a few other options...

Step 1: Check your mount options.

When I tried to mount a vfat filesystem in Fedora, these were the options presented:

```
$ grep vfat /proc/mounts
/dev/loop0 /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75 vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,\
  codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Obviously `iocharset=ascii` is sub-optimal.  When I re-mount with the option `iocharset=utf8` it correctly represents the correct `iocharset` value:

```
$ grep vfat /proc/mounts
/dev/loop0 /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75 vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,\
  codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Example:

```
$ cp 测试.pdf /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/
cp: cannot create regular file '/tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/测试.pdf': Invalid argument
$ sudo mount -o loop,iocharset=utf8  ~/vfat.img /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/
$ cp 测试.pdf /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/
$ echo $?
0
$ ls -li /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/
total 0
167 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Sep 25 21:57 测试.pdf
```

Next, the situation of having problems moving files happens more often than you think.  Depending on the exact details of the situation, I've used variations on a number of the [answers cited here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235396/mv-file-with-garbled-name-by-inode-number).

To summarize these a bit:

Option 1: Move the file by reference.

The file is stored on an `ext*` filesystem by it's "inode" number.  You can verify/see this number by adding the `-i` flag to `ls`:

```
$ ls -i
3312906 测试.pdf
```

From here, it's possible to reference the file by it's inode number with the `find` command and then execute a `mv` command indirectly:

```
$ find * -inum 3312906  -exec mv "{}"  /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/  \;
```

Option 2: Odd escaping

Both `find` and `xargs` have the ability to use `NUL` (`\0`) characters for field separation, allowing for working around crazy characters:

```
$ find . -inum 3312906 -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' /tmp/tmp.Migr78uZ75/
```

Comment: The option `iocharset=utf8` solved the problem. This is exhaustive, great answer. Thank you!